# use of unresolved identifier swift 3.0

Tags: json, xcode, swift3

I am trying to take a json array from php and save it as an array within xcode to work with.  I am able to pull the json data and print it inside the xcode terminal, but for some reason I can' reference the array without getting an error.  Here is my code!!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //connect to website
    let url = URL(string:"******")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil
        {
            print("error")
        }
        else
        {
            if let content = data
            {
                do
                {
                    //download JSON data from php page, display data
                    let SongArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as Any
                    print(SongArray)
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()

    //Make buttons

    var buttonY:  CGFloat = 20
    for song in SongArray {
        let SongButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x, 50, y: buttonY, width, 250, height: 30))

    }

} //close viewDidLoad
```

I get an error when I loop through SongArray

It says: 'Use of Unresolved Identifier "SongArray"'. even though I 'let' it into existence right before..

Comment: Not related, but why do you use a variable name containing `Array` but cast the object to `Any` (aka *I-have-no-idea*)? This will most likely cause a compile error.

Comment: Not sure, I just know the 'as Any' part was involved in the formatting of jsonserialization in swift.. i think its just to capture the data no matter what type of json object it is

Comment: **You** obviously know what type it is so tell the compiler.

Comment: well I wasn't familiar with json serialization when I wrote this code it was apart of the template basically..  So if I told the compiler it was an array, I'd be able to call it in the loop?

Comment: Yes, if it's a Swift `Array` containing the actual type, do **not** use `NSArray`. By the way `.mutableContainers` is completely meaningless in Swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not work for several reasons:

- You will get compiler errors because you are ignoring the actual types. `Any` is always the worst solution if you know it's a more specific type.
- `URLSession` works asynchronously, the `song` loop will be never executed. You have to put it **into** the completion block

---

According to the given JSON the object is an array of `String` arrays.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //connect to website
    let url = URL(string:"******")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("error:", error!)
        }
        else {

            do {
                //download JSON data from php page, display data
                let songArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! [[String]]
                print(songArray)
                //Make buttons

                var buttonY:  CGFloat = 20
                for song in songArray {
                    let songButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: buttonY, width: 250, height: 30))
                }
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()

} //close viewDidLoad
```

As a side effect that resolves magically the `use of unresolved identifier` error in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Because `SongArray` is inside `dataTask` closure and is out of scope.
You can do something like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //connect to website
    var SongArray: Any
    let url = URL(string:"******")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil
        {
            print("error")
        }
        else
        {
            if let content = data
            {
                do
                {
                    //download JSON data from php page, display data
                    SongArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as Any
                    print(SongArray)
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()

    //Make buttons

    var buttonY:  CGFloat = 20
    for song in SongArray {
        let SongButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x, 50, y: buttonY, width, 250, height: 30))

    }

}
```

Comment: thanks! but now the error has changed to " 'Type' Any does not conform to protocol 'Sequence' ".

Comment: This is another error. Change `as Any` to `as Array` or `Dictionary` depends the data downloaded

Comment: when I made that change it says it expects Any not Array, and it is an array so if it works I'm keepin it

Comment: Force downcast with `as! NSDictionary` or `as! NSArray`

Answer (score -1):

The answer was a combination of comments made

```
//connect to website
    var SongArray: Array<Any>
    let url = URL(string:"http://cgi.soic.indiana.edu/~team22/SongData.php")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil
        {
            print("error")
        }
        else
        {
            if let content = data
            {
                do
                {
                    //download JSON data from php page, display data
                    let SongArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as Any
                    print(SongArray)
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()

    //Make buttons

    var buttonY:  CGFloat = 20
    for song in SongArray {
```